# Warning message while using a window function in SparkSQL dataframe

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the below warning message when I use the window function in SparkSQL. Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Warning Message:

`No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.`

My Code:

```scala
def calcPrevBrdrx(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val w = Window.orderBy("existing_col1")
    df.withColumn("new_col", lag("existing_col2", 1).over(w))
}
```

Comment: Basically I am adding a new column (new_col) which is just a 1 row slide down compared to 'existing_col2' by using window lag function.

Comment: I could see in the new dataframe the new column 'new_col' is created correctly as expected. But I am getting warning message as said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is exactly what it says. In general, when you use a window function you would first partition by some column and only then order. So for example if you had logs for a user you might partition by the user and then order by time which would do the sorting separately for each user.

If you do not have a partition by then you are sorting on the entire data frame. This would basically mean you have a single partition. All data from all the dataframe would move to that single partition and be sorted.

This would be slow (you are shuffling everything and then sorting everything) and worse this means that all your data need to fit in a single partition which is not scalable.

You should probably take a look at your logic to make sure you really need to sort everything instead of partitioning by something before.

Comment: Yes I tried to do this by Window.orderBy("existing_col1").partitionBy("existing_col2","existing_col3")

Comment: Yes I tried to do this by Window.orderBy("existing_col1").partitionBy("existing_col2","existing_col3") But the new field 'new_col' which I am adding is getting null for all the rows.

Comment: If you do partitionby two columns then you have sorted data per tuple. If there is just one value per tuple you would get null (as there is no lag). Since you are trying to find lag for column "existing_col2" I would do: Window.partitionBy("existing_col2").orderBy("existing_col1")

Answer (score -1):

If your logic demands to use order by without partition clause, may be because you don't have anything else to partition on or it doesn't make sense for the window function used, you can add a dummy value like below -

`.withColumn("id", explode(typedLit((1 to 100).toList)))`

This will create an id field with value from 1 to 100 for each row in original dataframe and use that in partition by clause ( partition by id) , it will launch 100 tasks. Total number of rows it will create will be current rows*100 .Make sure you drop the id field and do distinct on result.