# How to iterate over a pyspark dataframe to increment a value and reset it to 0

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with the following fields:
dt = timestamp (one row per hour)
rain_1h = rain in mm that hour

Now I need to calculate the number of Dry Hours, when it doesnt rain, so it must increment it when it doesnt rain, and when it rains it should reset to 0.

I tried the following:

```
def calculate_dry_hours(df):
    window_spec = Window.orderBy("dt")
    
    # Create a column "RainyHour" to flag rainy hours
    df = df.withColumn('DryHour', when(col('rain_1h') == 0, 1).otherwise(0))
    df = df.withColumn('RainHour', when(col('rain_1h') > 0, 1).otherwise(0))  

    # Create a column "lag_rain1h" for the lag of "rain_1h"
    df = df.withColumn("lag_rain1h", lag("rain_1h").over(window_spec))
    dry_hour_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('dt')

    df = df.withColumn('DryHourCount', when(col('RainHour') == 0, sum('DryHour').over(dry_hour_window)).otherwise(0))
    df = df.withColumn('DryHourCount', when(col('RainHour') == 0 & lag('RainHour', 1).over(dry_hour_window) == 1, 0).otherwise(col('DryHourCount')))
   
    return df
```

However this is not giving the desired results

Comment: Can you post a testable df fragment (say 10-20 records) and the expected result for it?

Comment: i'm unable to understand how the output should look like. a df with expected result would be great here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all rows count how many hours before that row had 0 mm rain. This gives a 'group id' and within this group we can simply count the rows.

Create some testdata for 1 day:

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import seed, randint
seed(42)
data=[(datetime.fromisoformat('2023-01-01T00:00:00') + timedelta(hours=h), randint(0,1)) for h in range(0,24) ]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ['dt', 'rain_1h'])
df.orderBy('dt').show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|                 dt|rain_1h|
+-------------------+-------+
|2023-01-01 00:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 01:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 02:00:00|      1|
|2023-01-01 03:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 04:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 05:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 06:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 07:00:00|      0|
|2023-01-01 08:00:00|      1|
|2023-01-01 09:00:00|      0|
[...]
```

Now calculate the 'group ids' and the row number within each group:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

group_window = Window.orderBy('dt')
hour_window = Window.partitionBy('dry_group').orderBy('dt')

df.withColumn('dry_group', F.sum((F.col('rain_1h')!=0).cast('int')).over(group_window)) \
  .withColumn('dry_hours_within_group', F.row_number().over(hour_window) - 1) \
  .show(n=30)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|                 dt|rain_1h|dry_group|dry_hours_within_group|
+-------------------+-------+---------+----------------------+
|2023-01-01 00:00:00|      0|        0|                     0|
|2023-01-01 01:00:00|      0|        0|                     1|
|2023-01-01 02:00:00|      1|        1|                     0|
|2023-01-01 03:00:00|      0|        1|                     1|
|2023-01-01 04:00:00|      0|        1|                     2|
|2023-01-01 05:00:00|      0|        1|                     3|
|2023-01-01 06:00:00|      0|        1|                     4|
|2023-01-01 07:00:00|      0|        1|                     5|
|2023-01-01 08:00:00|      1|        2|                     0|
|2023-01-01 09:00:00|      0|        2|                     1|
|2023-01-01 10:00:00|      0|        2|                     2|
|2023-01-01 11:00:00|      0|        2|                     3|
|2023-01-01 12:00:00|      0|        2|                     4|
|2023-01-01 13:00:00|      0|        2|                     5|
|2023-01-01 14:00:00|      0|        2|                     6|
|2023-01-01 15:00:00|      0|        2|                     7|
|2023-01-01 16:00:00|      1|        3|                     0|
|2023-01-01 17:00:00|      0|        3|                     1|
|2023-01-01 18:00:00|      1|        4|                     0|
|2023-01-01 19:00:00|      1|        5|                     0|
|2023-01-01 20:00:00|      0|        5|                     1|
|2023-01-01 21:00:00|      0|        5|                     2|
|2023-01-01 22:00:00|      1|        6|                     0|
|2023-01-01 23:00:00|      1|        7|                     0|
+-------------------+-------+---------+----------------------+
```

*Remark*: Spark will print out a warning

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

for the first window `group_window`. Using Spark for iterating over a complete dataframe is not ideal, as Spark moves all data to a single executor. There are some answers on this topic (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41236206/2129801) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41313488/2129801)) on SO.

Comment: but this one doesnt show the number of dry hours, however looks very close to the final answer, so if it doesnt rain in 10 hours, then that field should have 10, and when it rains it must be reset to 0

Comment: simply replacing '==' with '!=' should do it

Comment: it did! thank you